# How to obtain these visual effects for headers without using Tikz?

Tags: packages, layout, overlap

I recently saw a document, which was created by Adobe Photoshop PDF. I mimicked its basic visual structure here with LaTeX:

[image: basic visual structure]

My question is about the colored underlying parts:

- I used *(non-tweaked, non-refactored)* Tikz to create them
- they can be anything, i.e. deviating from just highlighting a line of text
- any size, position, overlap, *(nice-to-have: shape)*  etc.

**How** to achieve such a visual effect with more "classical" LaTeX means, i.e. without Tikz **?**

E.g. `\makebox{0cm}{ }`, `\raisebox`, `\vspace{-1cm}` and similar don't seem to provide the neccessary overwrite and transparency, at least in my hands.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\parindent0pt

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
    h1/.style={font={\huge\bfseries}},
    h2/.style={font={\Large}},
    ]
    \node[fill=green!40!gray!40,
          minimum width=.6\textwidth,
          minimum height=13mm]  at (0,1) {};
    \node[h1]                   at (0,1.5) {Some Title /};
    \node[h1]                   at (0,0.5) {Title continued};
    \node[h2]                   at (0,-.3) {Some Subheader};
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

Text, which introduces the topic. \dots

\begin{center}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
    h3/.style={font={\large\bfseries}},
    ]
    \node[fill=orange!80!red!20,
          minimum width=1\textwidth,
          minimum height=6mm]   at (0,1) {};
    \node[h3]                   at (0,1.3) {What can be done about this?};
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

Some more text, and:

 \begin{itemize}
  \item some issues
  \item some remarks
  \item additional information
 \end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You could just put a colored `\rule` that you shift to where it should be. If you place the rule before you place the text, there is no transparency issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make use of colored `\rule`s. At least, you can create simple rectangles with this approach. If you typeset them before typesetting text, you won't run into transparency issues (after all, you put the colored noded before typesetting the text in your original code as well). Of course, this would require some tweaking for correct placement, but I guess with a bit of math, this should totally be doable:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\parindent0pt

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
 \vspace*{-1\baselineskip}
 \makebox(\textwidth,0pt){\raisebox{-4cm}{\textcolor{green!40!gray!40}{\rule{.6\textwidth}{13mm}}}}
 {\huge\bfseries Some Title / \\[10pt] \huge\bfseries Title continued \par}
 \vspace*{0.2cm}

 {\Large Some Subheader \par}
 
\end{center}

Text, which introduces the topic. \dots

\begin{center}
 \vspace*{-1\baselineskip}
 \makebox(\textwidth,0pt){\raisebox{-1.8cm}{\textcolor{orange!80!red!20}{\rule{\textwidth}{6mm}}}}
 {\large\bfseries What can be done about this? \par}
 \vspace*{0.2cm}
\end{center}

Some more text, and:

 \begin{itemize}
  \item some issues
  \item some remarks
  \item additional information
 \end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you need other shapes, you could also look into the relatively new [`l3draw` package](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3experimental/l3draw.pdf) which has quite an astonishing functionality do draw things. I would guess that it is much more lightweight than Ti*k*Z:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{l3draw}

\parindent0pt

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\drawPathEllipse}{ m m m m }{
    \vbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box {
        \draw_begin:
            \color_fill:n { #1 }
            \draw_path_ellipse:nnn { 0cm , 0cm } { #3 , 0cm } { 0cm , #4 }
            \draw_path_use_clear:n { fill }
        \draw_end:
    }
    \box_set_ht:Nn \l_tmpa_box { #2 }
    \box_set_dp:Nn \l_tmpa_box { 0pt }
    \box_use:N \l_tmpa_box
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
 \drawPathEllipse{green!40!black!20}{-0.25cm}{4cm}{1cm}
 
 {\huge\bfseries Some Title / \\[10pt] \huge\bfseries Title continued \par}
 \vspace*{0.2cm}

 {\Large Some Subheader \par}
\end{center}

Text, which introduces the topic. \dots

\begin{center}
 \drawPathEllipse{yellow!40!red!20}{-0.1cm}{5cm}{0.5cm}
 
 {\large\bfseries What can be done about this? \par}
\end{center}

Some more text, and:

 \begin{itemize}
  \item some issues
  \item some remarks
  \item additional information
 \end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, thank you :) I was struggeling with the shift-part.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the l3draw package: interesting development.